# cse popular queries are not showing exactly like in google search results

Tags: google-api, google-search, google-custom-search, google-search-api

Hi I have multiple popular queries in my cse panel I copied the code to show the popular queries in my website but they do not appear like they should be they appear like this [query1](http://link.com)

How can I show the popular queries exactly as google search results with the same style ?